# laravel MethodNotAllowedHttpException No message error

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

I'm submitting a form but it shows me the error of

> MethodNotAllowedHttpException No message

This is my code.

create.blade.php

```
 <form method="POST" action="/Form/show">
        {{csrf_field()}}
        <div class="form-group">
            First Name : <input class="form-control" type="text" placeholder="John" name="first_name"/>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            Last Name : <input class="form-control" type="text" placeholder="Wick" name="last_name"/>
        </div>
  <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Submit</button>
    </form>
```

ResourceController.php

```
public function show(){

    $f_data = \App\revesion_registration::all();
    return view('Form.show', compact('f_data'));
}


public function create(){
    return view('form.create');
}

public function store(){
    revesion_registration::create(request(['first_name','last_name']));
return redirect('show');

}
```

web.php

```
Route::resource('Form','ResourceController');
```

route:list

```
GET|HEAD | Form | Form.index |App\Http\Controllers\FormsController@index
POST     | Form | Form.store | App\Http\Controllers\FormsController@store
GET|HEAD | Form/create | Form.create | App\Http\Controllers\FormsController@create 
GET|HEAD | Form/{Form} | Form.show | App\Http\Controllers\FormsController@show
```

Comment: Can you show your php artisan route:list result.

Comment: GET|HEAD  | Form  | Form.index   |App\Http\Controllers\FormsController@index

POST      | Form         | Form.store | App\Http\Controllers\FormsController@store

GET|HEAD | Form/create | Form.create | App\Http\Controllers\FormsController@create

 GET|HEAD  | Form/{Form}  | Form.show  | App\Http\Controllers\FormsController@show    | web

Comment: i have 3 more for update , destroy and edit

Answer (score 0):

The `show()` method only accepts `GET` requests, which is what your form is attempting to `POST` to. Assuming you are trying to create a new record in the database, you should update your form to:

```
<form method="POST" action="Form">
```

If you have added / updated routes, run the command `php artisan route:clear` to clear the route cache.

Comment: Run the command `php artisan route:clear` to make sure the route cache has been updated.

Comment: Update your answer with what you've done so I can see. Just saying it doesn't work doesn't help me.

Comment: i ran the command     php artisan route:clear     but still getting the error

Comment: OK. I think the problem is that you need to update the form to: `<form method="POST" action="Form">`.

Answer (score 0):

In your `create.blade.php` file,

```
<form method="POST" action="{{ route('Form.store') }}">
```

In Your controller store method,

```
public function store(Request $request)
  {
    revesion_registration::create(request(['first_name','last_name']));
return redirect(route('Form.create'));

  }
```

Answer (score 0):

While Using the

`Route::resource('routename','ControllerClassName');`

For Eg We have post model

`Route::resource('posts','PostController');`

It Will register the  following routes

```
Route::get('/posts',  'PostController@index')->name('posts.index');
Route::get('/posts/create',  'PostController@create')->name('posts.create');
Route::post('/posts',  'PostController@store')->name('posts.store');
Route::get('/posts/{post}',  'PostController@show')->name('posts.show');
Route::get('/posts/{post}/edit',  'PostController@edit')->name('posts.edit');
Route::put('/posts/{post}',  'PostController@update')->name('posts.update');
Route::delete('/posts/{post}',  'PostController@destroy')->name('posts.destroy');
```

Now Comming To your Problem

Your Model Name is `revesion_registration` and your Table Name will be `revesion_registrations`

Solution

You need to register the route as

```
revesionregistrations
```

`Route::resource('revesionregistrations','RevesionRegistrationController');` in `web.php`

and in your create form

```
<form name='add_revesionregistrations' method='post' enctype="multipart/form-data" action="{{ route('revesionregistrations.store') }}" autocomplete="off">
                    {{csrf_field()}} 

   <input type="text" name='name' class="form-control">
                   <input type="submit" value="Submit">
                </form>
```

Your Problem Will be Solved

**`Now My Suggestion`**

While Creating the Model Dont Create in lower case

not `revesion_registration`

Try `php artisan make:model RevesionRegistration -a`

and

If You are Performing only **`CRED`** Operations Use  `Route::resource('routename','ControllerClassName');`